# How to circle an option/value in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to circle a value on the basis of some expression in SSRS report? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not have built in functionality to draw circles specifically. There are a few alternatives such as using an image or an indicator. However, there is one big issue with any of these. And that is the fact that SSRS doesn't allow these to overlap other items. So whatever you were trying to circle, probably an expression, will just get moved around the image as opposed to staying in the center of it.

So the next best option would probably be to use a rectangular border instead. Hope this helps.